# MathJax is rendering twice

Tags: mathjax

I have a MathJax demo that can be viewed at [Online Demo](http://js.do/sun21170/mathjax).

In this demo, I have some Tex markup within a div that gets rendered perfectly by MathJax.

But, if I programatically add some Tex markup to the above div by clicking `Add Math Markup` button  followed by clicking `Rerender Math Markup` button, then it results in repeated rendering of previously rendered Math markup. This can be seen in following video: [Math being rendered repeatedly](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzhl0S7bXwuySTZyZjBudkFMQ0k/view)

All I am doing when `Rerender Math Markup` button is clicked is calling the following method `MathJax.Hub.Typset(divElement)`. The divElement is the div to which Tex markup was added programatically.

**Demo code for my situation**

```
<script>
   function reRenderMath() {
   var div = document.getElementById("mathMarkup");
   //render Math for newly added  Tex markup
    MathJax.Hub.Typeset(div);
   }
    function addMath() {
    var div = document.getElementById("mathMarkup");
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + "$$\sin^{-1}.6$$";
    document.getElementById("btnRenderMath").disabled = false;
    }
</script>
<script type="text/x-mathjax-config">
   MathJax.Hub.Config({tex2jax: {inlineMath: [['$','$'], ['\\(','\\)']]}});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
   src="http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="addMath();return false;" id="btnAddMath" >Add Math Markup</button>
<button type="button" onclick="reRenderMath();return false;" id="btnRenderMath" disabled>Rerender Math Markup</button>
<div id="mathMarkup">
   $$x^2 = x +2$$
</div>
```

**Screen shot of repeated rendering**

[image: Repeated endering of MathJax]

Comment: Don't reuse innerHTML like that. Properly append the content as a new child. Also, the CDN has been retired.

Comment: Thanks. It works now. I modified the demo by adding Tex markup as a textnode to original div rather than adding Tex markup to inner html of this div . The modified demo is at  http://js.do/sun21170/mathjaxmodified

Comment: I used another approach to achieve this, though your approach is best. The demo for this new approach is at http://js.do/sun21170/mathjaxdualrenderingsolution. The problem was that for each MathJax rendering a `script` tag is created and this script tag was causing double rendering when MathJax.Hub.Typeset method was called. So, I remove these script elements just before calling MathJax.Hub.Typeset and then in callback just after the method returns, I add these script elements to where they were originally.  Not sure if this is a faulty approach?

Answer (score 1):

[@Sunil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/812970/sunil) thanks for the answer

Summarizing:

Required script:

```js
    var MathJaxUtils = (function () {
    let obj = {};
    let scripts = null;

    obj.render = function (element) {
        scripts = new Array();
        $(element).find("script[id^='MathJax-Element']").each(function () {
            scripts.push({
                displayElement: $(this).prev("div")[0],
                scriptElement: this
            });
        });
        //remove all html within MathJax script tags so it doesn't get typset again when Typeset method is called
        $(element).find("script[id^='MathJax-Element']").remove();
        //render Math using original MathJax API and in callback re-insert the MathJax script elements in their original positions
        MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, element, typeSetDone]);
    };

     //callback for Typeset method
     function typeSetDone() {
         for (var i = 0; i < scripts.length; i++) {
             $(scripts[i].displayElement).after(scripts[i].scriptElement);
         }
         //reset scripts variable
         scripts = [];
     };

    return obj;
 }());
```

Basic use:

```js
let elem = document.getElementById("mathContainer");
MathJaxUtils.render(elem);
```

Demo:
[math-jax-test](https://github.com/anayarojo/math-jax-test)